# I am unable to display toaster first before redirecting to another page

Tags: angularjs

I have used toaster in the Angular script file but  the toaster is not displayed before redirecting to another page.

HTML

```
<div>
    <toaster-container toaster-options="{'time-out': 3000, 'close-
         button':true, 'animation-class': 'toast-top-center','position-
            class':'toast-top-full-width' } "></toaster-container>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ngAnimate', 'toaster'])
    .controller('logincontroller', function($scope, toaster, $window, $http) {
        $scope.checkdata = function() {
            toaster.error("", " Invalid Credential");
            $window.location.href =
                "/myproject/admin/PendingRequests.html";
        }
    });
```

Whats wrong with the code?

Comment: which toaster are you using? the plugin url?

Comment: If you remove the page redirect line, does the toaster message display properly?

Comment: yes, it display if i remove redirect line

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is that the toaster container is inside your current page. Can you try moving the toaster container to the index.html?

Comment: toaster container already there in index page.

Comment: Can you please share your index.html?

Comment: The toast can not be shown because you immediately go to the new URL. You should probably put a timeout on the URL change.